# Touchpad not Working on Asus Laptop A540LJ

Tags: touchpad, asus

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my new Asus Laptop. The cursor moves and the clicks work but features like 2 finger scroll, edge scroll and 2 finger right click etc are not working.

I really love Ubuntu, but these are nifty features and I am used to them. How can I get them working?

Here's the output of `xinput`

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The driver for your Touchpad (FTE1001) was only added to the kernel in version 4.10.

Ubuntu 16.04 currently uses Kernel v4.8 (or v4.4). It will receive v4.10 in four months.

In the meantime - you can:

- Install Ubuntu 17.04 (which uses Kernel v4.10); or
- Follow the instructions here: https://github.com/vlasenko/hid-asus-dkms

Following the instructions at the link above will install a DKMS driver. A DKMS driver is basically a driver that wasn't built with the rest of the Kernel. However - it is the same driver that is used in Kernel v4.10.

Comment: Apologies - it looks like Ubuntu have back-ported this driver to their Kernel v4.8. So as long as you are running Kernel v4.8.0-34 (or later) - you shouldn't need to do anything.